# A surface consists of all points P such that the distance from P to the plane y = 1 is twice the distance from P to the point (0,−2, 0).

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The question asks me to find the equation for this surface and identify it. I've already reached to the point of $4x^2+3(y+3)^2+4z^2=-6$ but my professor's solution is given as $4x^2+3(y+3)^2+4z^2=12$. I am unsure of where I might have gone wrong. I don't understand how my professor got to the number $12$. Also, yes, I understand that if I divide whatever number on the right side, I will get the form of some equation I will recognise. I am not concerned about identifying the surface, I'm unsure how to match my equation with my professor's answer.

Comment: What does your calculation look like?

Comment: I set up the equation as sqrt((y-1)^2))=2*sqrt((x^2)+(y+2)^2+(z^2)). Then I square both sides and begin solving. Eventually I reached y^2-2y+1=4x^2+4(y^2+4y+4)+4z^2. Then I distributed the 4 to all the y's on the right side. Then I subtracted the constants and completed the square.

Comment: please edit your question using Latex . https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/946006

Comment: The error appears to be somewhere in the steps where you "subtracted the constants and completed the square." This is why if you want a specific answer about where your mistake is, you will have to **edit** the question to show every single formula you wrote with no details left out. Someone has kindly showed you how to format the polynomials to make them readable.

Comment: We can see immediately that your equation $4x^2+3(y+3)^2+4z^2=-6$ cannot be correct, because the left side is positive or zero and the right side is negative, whereas it is obvious that the equations that define the surface have at least one solution.

Answer (score 1):

2×$d_2((0,-2,0),(x,y,z))=$ $dist((x,y,z)\rightarrow (Q))$ where $(Q)$ is the plane of equation $y=1$ $\implies$ $2\sqrt{x^2+(y+2)^2+z^2}=\frac{|y-1|}{\sqrt{0^2+1^2+0^2}}$ squaring both sides you will get $4x^2+4y^2+16y+16+z^2=y^2-2y+1$
$4x^2+3y^2+18y+4z^2=-15$ adding 27 at the both sides of the equality $4x^2+3y^2+18y+27+4z^2=-15+27$
$4x^2+3y^2+18y+27+4z^2=12$

Comment: But why do we add 27?

Comment: since we are completing the square of $3y^2+18y$ so first we take 3 common and we get $3(y^2+6y)=3(y^3+6y+9-9)=3(y+3)^2-9)=3(y+3)^2-3×9=3(y+3)^2-27$ thats why i add 27 both sides

Comment: @user1219275 i think your mistake is that you add 9 instaed of 27 . so you forget to multiply 9 by 3 when taking 3 common and comleting the square .

Comment: you are welcome